# Volume of ellipsoid in "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies"

Tags: special-relativity

On Einstein's famous paper, in the section on the transformation of light energy between frames of reference, Einstein devises a thought experiment to determine it. He imagines two frames of reference, $K$ and $k$, in which $k$ moves relative to $K$ with velocity $v$ along the x-axis. The coordinates and time in frame $K$ are $x, y, z,$ and $t$. The coordinates in time for $k$ are $\xi, \eta, \zeta,$ and $\tau$. He imagines that a plane light wave travels at an angle from the axis with $l, m,$ and $n$ being the cosines between the wave-normal and the three axis, respectively. He then imagines an imaginary spherical surface which moves in the same direction as the light, such that as it travels, it always encloses the same 'bit' of light. The equation for this sphere is
$$(x-clt)^2+(y-cmt)^2+(z-cnt)^2=R^2$$
To find the volume of this 'sphere' in the $k$ frame of reference, he applies the Lorentz Transformation to the equation of the sphere and obtaining an ellipsoid. Setting $\tau=0$:
$$(\beta\xi-l\beta\frac{v}{c}\xi)^2+(\eta-m\beta\frac{v}{c}\xi)^2+(\eta-n\beta\frac{v}{c}\xi)^2=R^2$$
So far so great, but then he states that "through a simple calculation" it can be shown that the ratio between the volume $S'$ of the ellipsoid and the volume $S$ of the sphere is
$$\frac{S'}{S}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}{1-l\frac{v}{c}}$$
What is this 'Simple Calculation' through which we can determine the volume of the ellipsoid?

Comment: This is really a mathematics question, I think : finding the volume of an ellipsoid (and that of a sphere) from the Cartesian equation. Have you tried looking this up in a mathematics resource?